# this is really annoying me how to remove all syntax colors of vim 7+

Tags: linux, vim, vi

Im using centos 5.5 and installed vim 7 
i defined syntax off in vimrc , and it removed me most of the syntax coloring , but i still
have colors when i move to curly braces , and when i search for string in source its paint me the result with yellow , all so when i do code completion its also with colors 
how do i remove all colors from vim i want it to be like old vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this stuff in `~/.vimrc`

- `set nohlsearch` - disables highlighted search
- `let g:loaded_matchparen=1` - disable brace/paren/bracket matching

Comment: Thanks! now how i torn off the colors of  : set nu (line numbers) .  
where all this commands defined , not in the vimrc ..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `vi` alias in your shell.

```
unalias vi
```

Comment: +1: I am not sure this answer is very helpful, but it is funny

Comment: @Peter: Fedora-derived distros alias `vi` to `vim` for normal users. Removing it causes vim to be invoked in compatibility mode, which does not include syntax highlighting (and other things, but if you hate syntax highlighting then you probably don't care about them either).

Comment: Turning compatibilty mode on changes a lot of things. E.g. pressing `u` twice in `vi` will undo the undo. Pressing `u` multiple times in `vim` will undo commands further down your command history. I would not think somebody who does not like colors also does not like undoing multiple commands.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try disabling syntax different way as <kbd>`:syntax=off`</kbd> doesn't turn off all the colors. Try using following <kbd>`:set syntax=off`</kbd> or i believe <kbd>`:set syntax=`</kbd> should work as well. This should disable all the colors, including Line number.

For follow up question regarding the colors of line numbers (if anyone want's to disable just that): 
you can disable the colors of the Line numbers by doing following: <kbd>`:hi LineNr ctermfg=white`</kbd>
(really not disabling, just making it white)

You can use <kbd>`:hi`</kbd> to change the colors of mostly anything in VI to make them white or any color, really.